# Problem in product operator

Tags: problem-solving, products

While solving an equation for a given algorithm [the equation is quite complex but it is similar to]
$\prod_{n=1,n\neq l}^L\frac{1}{2+\lambda_n}$

I stumbled on a situation where $L=1$ and $l=1$. This means that the only value that $n$ can take is $1$ which is also forbidden given the conditioned $n\neq l$.
i tried ignoring the product operator in that specific situation and just solving $\frac{1}{2+\lambda_n}$ for n=1. This produced a false result. 
this maybe a silly question but how should i act in this situation ?
[side note: the value prduced by this expression is later inserted into a larger equation in order to solve the algorithm]
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, the empty product has the value $1$.

Similarly, the empty sum has the value $0$.

There are times when these defaults do not make sense, but those times are context-dependent.

Comment: yeah this solved the issue, thanks!